# Wix : how to install a shared folder

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017, wix, wix3.11

I'm running WiX 3.11 with a C# VSTO add-in.
I need to create a feature that will install a folder, register it for sharing with everyone and remove the share upon uninstall.

I've tried 2 different approaches with no success (names and Ids are changed for simplification) :

1. With the help of the links below, I've tried to create permissions when the folder is created :
   [WiX set App_Data folder permission to modify for NetworkService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527939/wix-set-app-data-folder-permission-to-modify-for-networkservice)
   [Wix: CustomAction to set Folder permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612634/wix-customaction-to-set-folder-permissions)
   [Set permissions for existing folders and files in ProgramData with WiX Toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239120/set-permissions-for-existing-folders-and-files-in-programdata-with-wix-toolset)

> ```
>  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">    
>    <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
>     <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name=".">
>      <Directory Id="FOLDERTOSHARE" Name="Share">
>        <Component Id="ShareFolderPermissions" Guid="SOMEGUID">
>          <CreateFolder>
>            <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
>          </CreateFolder>
>        </Component>
>      </Directory>
>    </Directory>
>  </Directory>
> ```

With ShareFolderPermissions referenced in my new feature.
I've tried tweaking it a bit but it didn't work for me.

2. My second solution was to try using Windows commands through CustomActions to get the job done (spoiler: I'll need CustomActions later anyway).
   It worked fine at some point but I've been unable to implement the whole process.

I used a non-english website to get set up on how to create a WiX CustomAction project to import into my Product.wxs file, and I'm giving below what helped me set up command lines in C#.
[How to use Windows command with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)
[Net share documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh750728(v=ws.11))

Product.wxs (xml):

```
<?if $(var.Configuration) = MyShareConfiguration?>
  <Property Id="SHAREFEATURE" Value="1" />
<?endif?>
  
<Feature Id="ShareFeature" Title="ShareSetup" Level="0">
  <Condition Level="1">SHAREFEATURE</Condition>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyShareFiles"/>
</Feature>
  
<CustomAction Id="CustomActionShareFolder" BinaryKey="CustomActionProject" DllEntry="ShareFolder" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomActionUnShareFolder" BinaryKey="CustomActionProject" DllEntry="UnShareFolder" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

<Binary Id="CustomActionProject" SourceFile="CustomActionProjectPath" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomActionShareFolder" After="InstallFiles"> SHAREFEATURE AND (NOT REMOVE) </Custom>
  <Custom Action="CustomActinUnShareFolder" Before="RemoveFiles"> SHAREFEATURE AND (REMOVE~="ALL") </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

CustomAction.cs in my CustomAction project (C#), logs are removed for clarity:

```
private static readonly string SHAREFEATURENAME= "MyShareFeatureName";
private static void ExecuteCMD(string command) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = "CMD.exe",
        Arguments = command,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "runas"
    };
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start(); 
}

[CustomAction] 
public static ActionResult ShareFolder(Session session)
{
    ActionResult result = ActionResult.Success;
    string directoryPath = session.GetTargetPath("FOLDERTOSHARE"); // See Directory setup in 1.
    string command = string.Format("/c net share {0}=\"{1}\"", SHAREFEATURENAME, directoryPath.Remove(directoryPath.Length - 1)); // Remove '\' at the end of the path

    try
    {
        ExecuteCMD(command);
    }     
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = ActionResult.Failure;
    }

    return result; 
}

[CustomAction] 
public static ActionResult UnShareFolder(Session session) 
{
    ActionResult result = ActionResult.Success;
    string command = string.Format("/c net share {0} /delete", SHAREFEATURENAME);

    try
    {
        ExecuteCMD(command);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = ActionResult.Failure;
    }

    return result; 
}
```

I've tested my command in a separate application project with hard coded values I got from my msi logs.

```
msiexec /i "C:\MyPackage\Example.msi" /L*V "C:\log\example.log"
```

Code from the separate project (names changed on purpose) :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string command = "/c net share SHAREFEATURENAME=\"MyFolderPath\"";
    //string command = "/c net share SHAREFEATURENAME /delete";

     Console.WriteLine("Command : " + command);

     Process cmd = new Process();
     cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
     cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
     cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
     cmd.Start();

     cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo test");
     cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
     cmd.StandardInput.Close();
     cmd.WaitForExit();
     Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

The code from the separate project works fine as long as VS runs as administrator.
As of my msi, I've set Impersonate="no" so it asks for elevated rights on install / uninstall.

Both command are correctly called and end with no error. However, the targeted folder is never shared.

Can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe - as far as I understand it - should be possible to achieve with built-in WiX constructs. Here are some pointers, I want to avoid too much code and markup duplication. Please DO follow link 2 at least. Link 1 is just for the record:

1. [Always try to avoid custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779) (I know you state you need them).
2. Perhaps try [this WiX sample for folder sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071189/129130)?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this tackles both my need for future CustomActions and my current issue. I've tested your solution and it works for me, I just need to modify it to take care of localization issues with the "Everyone" keyword. I really appreciate you posted the first link, I had no idea this existed and it will definitely help me get better with WiX.

Comment: Great, please have one more look at that custom action link. I added a section a bit down from the top. Might be well known to you. Debugging custom actions. Do avoid them though if possible.